# How to copy references of elements of one vector to another vector?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, function-object, reference-wrapper

I have a `vector`:

```
std::vector<island> sea;
```

And now I want to hold pointers to all elements of this `vector` in another `vector`. But just for a personal exercise I want to do this in a fancy C++ style, so instead of `std::vector<const island*> p_sea` I type:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const island>> r_sea;
```

And now I'd like to populate this new `vector` with references:

```
std::transform(sea.begin(), sea.end(),
               std::back_inserter(r_sea),
               std::cref<island>
);
```

The way I understand it, from cppreference articles, the fourth argument of `transform` should be a function that takes const references to elements from the source range and returns elements of the destination range; and this is exactly what `std::cref<island>` does: it takes `const island&` as arguments and returns `std::reference_wrapper<const island>`. So I  believe this should work??

However, it doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>


struct island {
    long long x,y; //coords
};

int main() {
    std::vector<island> sea;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const island>> r_sea;

    std::transform(sea.begin(), sea.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(r_sea),
                   std::cref<island>
    );

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following compilation errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:19:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(std::vector<island>::iterator, std::vector<island>::iterator, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const island> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
     );
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/algorithm:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4166:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _UnaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation)
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4166:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:19:5: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function ‘cref<island>’
     );
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/algorithm:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4203:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter1, class _IIter2, class _OIter, class _BinaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation)
     transform(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1,
     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:4203:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:19:5: note:   could not resolve address from overloaded function ‘cref<island>’
     );
```

https://ideone.com/E80WXH

What am I doing wrong?

...I'm back to evil C pointers.

Comment: Try `std::reference_wrapper<const island>` instead of `std::reference_wrapper<const island*>`.

Comment: @cdhowie typo; doesn't fix compilation errors; am removing the typo from the question right now.

Comment: Your problem is that `std::cref` is overloaded. You need to disambiguate which overload to use.

Comment: @StoryTeller how?

Comment: Why don’t you post your real code?

Comment: @cdhowie Typo fixed, compilation errors persist.

Comment: @gaazkam An MVCE would be particularly helpful for questions like this.

Comment: @manni66 The problem is that this *is* a part of real code. Algorithmic task. Pathfinding among a grid of islands. I need to have the islands sorted in a few ways at the same time. Am I supposed to post the whole pathfinding algorithm? This would not be Minimal VCE!!

Comment: @cdhowie as above.

Comment: @gaazkam MVCE doesn't mean "paste all of your code." For example, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7205c3e2f5702d0b) is a sufficient MVCE for this specific problem.

Comment: @cdhowie Well I posted this on ideone and linked to it, OK I now understand this wasn't enough, fixed the quesion, is it OK now?

Comment: @gaazkam Yes, that's perfect. Off-site resources like ideone are good to augment a question, but we shouldn't depend on them for a good question. If ideone goes away, we don't want your question to stop making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::cref` is overloaded. Merely specifying the template argument is not enough to disambiguate between the overloads. You have two options:

1. Cast it

   ```
   static_cast<std::reference_wrapper<const island>(*)(const island&)>(std::cref<island>)
   ```
2. Lift the name up to a functor object (a lambda). like @Yakk proposed.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `std::cref<island>` with `[](auto&x){return std::cref<island>(x);}`, assuming [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), replace `auto` with `island const`.

`cref` has overloads, you cannot pass the overload set as an object, as overload sets are not objects.